# Setting an alarm with AlarmManager not firing

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So I've been following a tutorial for setting an alarm using the AlarmManager and I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong. Do I need to override the onReceive method?

I'm using the DatePicker and TimePicker widgets and getting my data from them and the user's input. My main class where I set the alarm is here:

```
public void initControls() {
        timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        setAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setAlarm);
        myCal = Calendar.getInstance();


        setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 

                myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());
                myCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                myCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                myCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                myCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                Intent triggered = new Intent("alarms.DisplayNotification");
                triggered.putExtra("NotificationId", 1);

                PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getBaseContext(), 0, triggered, 0);

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                        myCal.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);
            }
        });

    }
```

My the other class I'm using is for using the notificationBar and displaying that the Alarm has fired.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);


    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotificationId");


    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.mt_study.Main_screen");
    i.putExtra("NotificationId", notifID);

    PendingIntent displayAlarm = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = new Notification(
            R.drawable.book, 
            "Time's up!",
            System.currentTimeMillis());

        CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Thats all";
        CharSequence message = "Alarm DONE";        
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, displayAlarm);

        //---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100 ms and
        // then vibrate for 500ms---
        notif.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};        
        nm.notify(notifID, notif);
        //---destroy the activity---
        finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alarm will attempt to create an Activity "alarms.DisplayNotification". I suspect that this isn't going to trigger your class. You probably need a different intent for the alarm:

```
Intent triggered = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

You may need to replace `this` with `this.getApplicationContent()`.

Comment: Another option would be to have the second activity implement an intent filter in the manifest which intercepts "alarms.DisplayNotification"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I thought that was weird when I was looking at the tutorial, but I changed it and it seems to have no effect. I'm setting the alarm for a minute ahead of right now.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the displayNotifications Class. I think I can handle it from here. Thanks for the help :)